# Why does adding a subroute give this warning when I have a component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
  <Route path="/users/:userId" component={UserShow}>
    <Route path="/location/:locationId" component={LocationShow} />
  </Route>
```

I see this warning in my chrome console:

> ```
> bundle.js:887 Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route
> children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored
> ```

If I shouldn't add a component to the /user/:userId route, where am I suppose to add the component UserShow then?

Comment: are you trying to display both `UserShow` and `LocationShow` when the path matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested routes should be added to the parent component directly:

```
const UserShow = props => (
  <div>
    <div>User info</div>
    <Route path={`${props.match.url}/location/:locationId`} component={LocationShow} />
  </div>
);

<Route path="/users/:userId" component={UserShow} />
```

`LocationShow` will only be rendered when the path matches `/users/:userId/location/:locationId`.

Comment: Is that route expression correct?  If I hard code it for a URL it works e.g. path="/users/9/location/:locationId" but yours doesn't.  Not sure what that backtick and $ is doing.

Comment: It's a template literal (makes string concat prettier): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Can you try logging `props.match`? If you are using a class, do `this.props.match`. `props.match.url` should be `/users/9` in your example.

Comment: I removed the questions in path="", and did this.path

Comment: ? What's `this.path`?